# Scan the file ,print all Errors , if no error found in the file Print "Nothing found" ONCE

Tags: java

If the keyword "ERROR" is not found in the file then print "Nothing Found" once, This code is scanning each line and printing the output for each line.But if "ERROR" is found in multiple lines it needs to print all the "ERROR found.

Any help will be appreciated!

```
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.util.Scanner;


    public class Scan {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {


    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("Users/home/test.txt"));
    while(s.hasNextLine()){
        //read the file line by line
    String nextLine = s.nextLine();
                //check if the next line contains the key word
        if(nextLine.contains("ERROR"))
        {
                  //whatever you want to do when the keyword is found in the file
            System.out.println("Failed" + " " + nextLine);
        }
        else if(nextLine.contains("Failed!")){
                System.out.println("Not Found");

        }


        }         

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see, this code will go through the file and print:

```
"Failed" + " " + nextLine
```

every time:

```
nextLine.contains("ERROR")
```

which is great! The problem is here:

```
else if(nextLine.contains("Failed!")){
            System.out.println("Not Found");

    }
```

where during every loop you will be checking if nextLine contains the string "Failed!", then print "Not Found".

and I don't think you want that.

Try this:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ErrorScanner
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("Users/home/test.txt"));
        boolean ifError = false;
        while(s.hasNextLine())
        {  
        String nextLine = s.nextLine();       
            if(nextLine.contains("ERROR"))
            {
                System.out.println("Failed" + " " + nextLine);
                ifError = true;
            }
        }     
        if(! ifError)
        {
            System.out.println("Nothing found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've corrected the sense of if (! ifError), print "Nothing found" & improved your class-name. You might also want to re-examine your logic about "Not Found every time in his original code", & edit your post.. If you did it might be worth a +1.

Comment: I was saying that his original code _wouldn't_ print "Not Found" every time.. `nextLine.contains("Failed!")` checks the _input_, not the _output_.  But if you edit your post, it might be worth a +1.

Comment: Ahh, I see now! Thanks for bringing that up. I will edit that as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

You want to have a flag bool foundError which is initialized to false, when you find an error set it to true, at the end of your file scan check the variable - if it is false then print your "nothing found" message.